# Drawer component in native-base shows the error 'Warning: Function components cannot be...'

Tags: react-native, native-base

I'm developing a new mobile app with Drawer component in `native-base`.
And I'm facing the error message below when clicking the Icon on the right side on the header.

```
Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRed()?
```

This is the `GIF` when clicking the icon.
https://gyazo.com/31c6483acfda7ad3c6239e6171dbe688

These are my code.

- App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { createDrawerNavigator,createAppContainer, createStackNavigator, DrawerItems } from 'react-navigation'
import { Container, Content, Header, Left } from 'native-base';
import { Router, Scene } from 'react-native-router-flux';

import HomeScreen from './src/screens/HomeScreen';
import NoticeScreen from './src/screens/NoticeScreen';
import UserScreen from './src/screens/UserScreen';

export default class App extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <Router>
        <Scene key='root'>
          <Scene key='HomeScreen' component={HomeScreen} hideNavBar={true} panHandlers={null}/>
          <Scene key='NoticeScreen' component={NoticeScreen} hideNavBar={true} panHandlers={null} />
          <Scene key='UserScreen' component={UserScreen} hideNavBar={true} panHandlers={null} />
        </Scene>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

- HomeScreen.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Image, ImageBackground, Text, Linking, ScrollView, StyleSheet, View, Dimensions, TouchableOpacity, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
import { Body, Container, Content, ListItem, List, Header, Icon, Left, Right, Thumbnail, Drawer } from "native-base";
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';

import SidebarContainer from '../containers/SidebarContainer';

export default class HomeScreen extends Component {

  openDrawer() {
    this.drawer._root.open();
  };

  closeDrawer() {
    this.drawer._root.close();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Drawer
        ref={(ref) => { this.drawer = ref; }}
        content={<SidebarContainer navigator={this._navigator} />}
        openDrawerOffset={0.4}
        tapToClose={true}
        onClose={() => this.closeDrawer}
        onOpen={() => this.openDrawer}
        styles={{ height: 100 }}
      >
        <ImageBackground source={require('../../assets/header/blue.jpg')} style={{ width: null }}>
          <Header style={{ backgroundColor: 'transparent' }}>
            <Left style={{ flexDirection: 'row'}}>
              <Icon onPress={this.openDrawer.bind(this)} type='MaterialIcons' name='menu' style={{ color: 'white', justifyContent: 'center' }} />
            </Left>
            <Body>
            </Body>
            <Right>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={Actions.UserScreen}>
                <Thumbnail small source={require('../../assets/thumbnail.png')} style={{ justifyContent: 'center' }} />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </Right>
          </Header>
        </ImageBackground>
      </Drawer>
    )
  }
}
```

- UserScreen.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Image, ImageBackground, Text, ScrollView, View } from 'react-native';
import { Body, Header, Icon, Left, Right, Thumbnail, Card, CardItem } from "native-base";
import { Drawer } from 'react-native-router-flux';

import SidebarContainer from '../containers/SidebarContainer';
import SmallHeadLineComponent from '../components/SmallHeadLineComponent';

export default class UserScreen extends Component {

  openDrawer() {
    this.drawer._root.open();
  };

  closeDrawer() {
    this.drawer._root.close();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Drawer
        ref={(ref) => { this.drawer = ref; }}
        content={<SidebarContainer navigator={this._navigator} />}
        openDrawerOffset={0.4}
        tapToClose={true}
        onClose={() => this.closeDrawer}
        onOpen={() => this.openDrawer}
        styles={{ height: 100 }}
      >

        <ImageBackground source={require('../../assets/header/blue.jpg')} style={{ width: null }}>
          <Header style={{ backgroundColor: 'transparent' }}>
            <Left style={{ flexDirection: 'row'}}>
              <Icon onPress={this.openDrawer.bind(this)} type='MaterialIcons' name='menu' style={{ color: 'white', justifyContent: 'center' }} />
            </Left>
            <Body>  
            </Body>
            <Right>
              <Icon onPress={() => (alert('Open Modal'))} type='MaterialIcons' name='mail' style={{ color: 'white', justifyContent: 'center' }} />
            </Right>
          </Header>
        </ImageBackground>

        <ScrollView style={{ paddingTop: 10 }}>
          <View style={{ flex:1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', marginTop: 10 }}>
            <Thumbnail large source={require('../../assets/thumbnail.png')} style={{ justifyContent: 'center' }}/>
          </View>
          <View>
            <Card style={{ marginLeft: 100, width: 200, justifyContent: 'center' }}>
              <CardItem style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
                <Body>
                  <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                    kikuchi.user
                  </Text>
                </Body>
              </CardItem>
            </Card>
          </View>
          <View>
            <SmallHeadLineComponent text={'Sample'} />
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </Drawer>
    )
  }
}
```

- SidebarCotainer.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, ImageBackground, Image, TouchableOpacity, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
import { Container, Content, Drawer, Header, Left, Icon, Body, Right, Thumbnail, List, ListItem } from 'native-base';
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';

export default class SidebarContainer extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <View style={{ height: 1000 }}>
          <Header style={{ height: 65, backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
            <Left>
              <Text style={{ paddingLeft: 10 }}>
                Sidebar Title
              </Text>
            </Left>
          </Header>
          <Content>
            <List>
              <ListItem button noBorder={true} onPress={Actions.HomeScreen} >
                <Icon type='Ionicons' name='md-home' />
                <Text style={{ paddingLeft: 10 }}>Home</Text>
              </ListItem>
              <ListItem button noBorder={true} onPress={Actions.NoticeScreen} >
                <Icon type='Ionicons' name='ios-notifications' />
                <Text style={{ paddingLeft: 10 }}>Notice</Text>
              </ListItem>
              <ListItem button onPress={Actions.SignInScreen} >
                <Icon type='Ionicons' name='ios-remove-circle-outline' />
                <Text style={{ paddingLeft: 10 }}>SignOut</Text>
              </ListItem>
            </List>
          </Content>
        </View>
      </Container>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand why I'm wrong.
I'm using `Drawer` component from `react-native-router-flux`. I thought I'm using the one from `native-base`.
I don't have to rely on the code completion in my IDE.